# Number of primes from $n!+1$ to $n!+n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Why aren't there any primes between $n!+1$ and $n!+n$ for all $n>1$? This question was on AHSME 1969 #23, but the question is trivial because it's multiple choice. However, I have no idea how to prove such a statement for infinitely large $n$.

Comment: Hint: $i$ divides $n!+i$, for all $2\le i\le n$.

Comment: It has no primes. This is to show you you can find an arbitrarily large sequence of consecutive composite numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smaller number that
starts $n+1$ consecutive
composite numbers
is
$P(n)
=\prod_{p \le n} p
$.
This is called
the *primorial* of $n$.

To show that
$P(n)+i$ is composite
for $1 \le i \le n$,
just note that
each $i$ is divisible
by a prime $\le n$,
and this prime also
divides $P(n)$.

$P(n)$ is much smaller
than $n!$,
because
$\ln(n!)
\approx n \ln n - n$
while
$\ln(P(n))
\approx n
$
(since
$\ln P(n)$
is Chebychev's function
$\theta(n)$).

Answer (score 4):

This was actually much easier than I had expected.
$$n!+i=i(\frac{n!}{i}+1)$$
Also, when $1<i<n$, both factors are integers greater than $1$.

(Credit to vadim123)

Answer (score 3):

For every number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that you can think of, I can give you a sequence of $n-1$ consecutive numbers, none of which is prime:

- $n!+2$ (divisible by $2$)
- $n!+3$ (divisible by $3$)
- $\dots$
- $n!+n$ (divisible by $n$)

BTW, this proves that there is no finite bound on the gap between two consecutive primes.